# Decision vs Optimization version for Problems of two Parameters

Tags: reductions, optimization, np-hard, decision-problem

Let's say I have an optimization problem called $k$-foo which asks for a solution of size $k$ minimizing some quality criterion.

Now the corresponding decision problem $foo(M)$ would be: 
 Is there a solution to foo with quality at least $M$ of size $k$.

For problems on one parameter (for example vertex cover) it is obvious that solving the optimization problem sovles the decision problem.

But here I do not see such a correspondance between the $k$-foo optimization problem and the $foo(M)$ decision problem. How does for example showing that $foo(M)$ is NP-hard implies that $k$-foo is NP-hard?

The $k$-center problem is an example of such a problem where the decision version takes the radius as input and asks wether a solution of size $k$ exists.

Comment: Only decision problems can be NP-hard. Optimization problems are not languages, they are (partial) functions.

Comment: NP is a complexity class of *languages*, not optimization problems. When you say that some optimization problem is in NP, you really mean that the corresponding decision problem is in NP.

Comment: [I was missing a *not* in my previous comment ]For a problem to be NP-hard it does NOT need to be in NP.

Comment: No, but being NP-hard is again a feature of languages rather than decision problems.

Comment: Thank you for raising this point.
There seems to be quite some confusion about this fact. While wikipedia is on my side "NP-hard problems may be of any type: decision problems, search problems, or optimization problems." [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard] some lecture notes indeed say that "A language is NP-hard, if...". Do you know of any reference to a well agreed definition?

Comment: @user695652 The book by Garey & Johnson (which I highly recommend) has a chapter about NP-hardness. They use the term for decision (using many-one-reductions) problems as well as for optimization problems (which they formalize as "string relations") using Turing reductions. Note that these are not two entirely different notions of NP-hardness. The latter is just a generalization of the first.  So defining a language to be "NP-hard, if..." is just fine, if you only have to deal with languages.

Answer (score 2):

Having more than one input doesn't change anything:

Consider an optimization problem $MinQ$:

> **Input:** $x, k$
>   **Output:** find $y$ satisfying $Q(x,k,y)$ which minimizes $f(x,k,y)$: 
>   $$g(x,k) = \min_{y : Q(x,k,y)} f(x,k,y)$$

The corresponding decision problem $Q$ is:

> **Input:** $x, k, l$
>   **Query:** is there a $y$ satisfying $Q(x,k,l)$ such that $f(x,k,y) \leq l$?

To solve the decision problem,
we can solve the optimization problem,
then check if the output is less than $l$.
I.e. there is a very easy reduction from $Q$ to $MinQ$:

> input: $x,k,l$
>   1. $m = MinQ(x,k)$
>   2. return $m \leq k$